# Can regex match Interleaved matches?

Tags: c#, regex, match, overlap

I have a pattern with opening tags and closing tags
e.g. `/*tag1_START*/ some content /*tag1_END*/ other text /*tag2_START*/ some content /*tag2_END*/`

and i use the Regex `\/\*([a-zA-Z0-9]+)_START\*\/(.*?)\/\*\1_END\*`

can see @ [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/fGKYSD/2)

BUT, There was a situation where the tags were interleaved (mistakingly):
e.g. `/*tag3_START*/ some /*tag4_START*/ content /*tag3_END*/ other /*tag4_END*/ content`

I can easily check the overlap in the matches, but REGEX does not return Both tags because it continue from the last char it matched...

Can i use Regex to find Overlapping matches or i need to write my own code ?

Comment: Sound like [recursion in Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26385984/recursive-pattern-in-regex).

Comment: Use lookarounds here [`\/\*([a-zA-Z0-9]+)_START\*\/(?=(.*?)\/\*\1_END\*)`](https://regex101.com/r/fGKYSD/3)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew just that it will find it... (i'll check for the actual overlap myself) just the Index and Length of all matchs

Comment: revo.. great... put it as an answer.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew you are partially correct, the match doesnt include the entire expression. but i traverse the capture groups anyway, so i do have the positions i need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lookarounds do assert rather than consume characters. However capturing groups still store matched parts in them. Just put overlapping part inside a positive lookahead:

```
\/\*([a-zA-Z0-9]+)_START\*\/(?=(.*?)\/\*\1_END\*)
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/fGKYSD/3)

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what i needed

Answer (score 0):

```
(?=\*([a-zA-Z0-9]+)_START\*\/(.*?)\/\*(\1)_END\*)
```

You will have to use lookahead and not capture anything.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/vsA3ZU/1

Comment: @TomerW did this not work