# How to remove all strings with brackets in C#?

Tags: c#, string

```
string data = "DisplayName=[s9dFSQ]Height=[rPBM7]User=[5cY]Date=[KJn7Zzd1f]";
```

How can I remove all values in the brackets?

I am planning to use something like

```
string result="";
string[] wholestring = data.Split('[');
foreach (string f in wholestring)
{
     result += f.Split("]")[0];
}
result.Replace('[','').Replace(']','');

//result would be: DisplayName=Height=User=Date=
```

I would appreciate if you could show a more proper way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that all brackets are paired up correctly and there is no nesting, you could use [`Regex.Replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Text_RegularExpressions_Regex_Replace_System_String_System_String_System_String_):

```
var withoutBrackets = Regex.Replace(withBrackets, @"\[[^\]]*\]" , "");
```

[Demo.](https://ideone.com/JlJk1N)

If you need your regex to work with nested brackets as well, see [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26385984/335858) for an in-depth explanation of how this can be done in .NET.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
static void Main()
{
    string data = "DisplayName=[s9dFSQ]Height=[rPBM7]User=[5cY]Date=[KJn7Zzd1f]";

    Console.WriteLine(RemoveBracketsContent(data)); // prints DisplayName=Height=User=Date=
}

static string RemoveBracketsContent(string data)
{
    string result = string.Empty;
    bool brackedStarted = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
    {
        if (data[i].Equals('['))
        {
            brackedStarted = true;
            continue;
        }
        else if (data[i].Equals(']'))
        {
            brackedStarted = false;
            continue;
        }

        if (brackedStarted)
        {
            continue;
        }

        result += data[i];
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks you very much. First answer seems to be shorter, I prefer using shorter codes.

Comment: @BeytoA. Never prefer shorter code, prefer code you can read and understand.