# How to get main block function using regex

Tags: regex, regex-group

I am trying to get the main function from a block of code using regex, I will try to exemplify.

For example:

```
MORE CODE HERE....

start_func function1

var v1 endvar
var v2 endvar

start_func function2

var v3 endvar

end_func

var v4 endvar

end_func

MORE CODE HERE....
```

I want to extract this from the example:

```
start_func function1

var v1 endvar
var v2 endvar

start_func function2

var v3 endvar

end_func

var v4 endvar

end_func
```

Basically, I am trying to extract everything which is inside of `start_func function1` using regex.
I tried some combinations in Python like:

```py
re.findall(r"^\s*start_func\s+\w+\s+.*?^\s*end_func\s*$", strin_to_search, re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)
```

but it is getting:

```
start_func function1

var v1 endvar
var v2 endvar

start_func function2

var v3 endvar

end_func
```

Comment: You can't match nested structures wth Python `re`, you will have to write a parser.

Comment: or use `regex`'s recursive features, ref. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26385984/recursive-pattern-in-regex