# Regex pattern recursively - in python

Tags: python, regex, algorithm, pattern-matching

I've been sitting on this for 2 days now, and still didn't find an effective way to do so.
Lets say we have the string:

> <**5629476219**<421fsaas42f>**14222**<2412f2<2421savsar21>12vsaf21>**412**<<<142avsa1>1a24>421>**421**>

The output I want:

> <562947621914222412421>

Well, recursively there might be data inside <> brackets, it could consist of numbers and letters - but the first level consists only of numbers.
I **bolded** out the data I want to extract.

I want to do this in Python. The naive way is to implement a bracket stack of course (that way I'll know if I'm inside an inner bracket or I'm in the 1st level) - but it's very inefficient going char by char.
I believe there is a good regex pattern I could use, but I haven't come up with something that works.

Can some with enough experience with regex give a little help?

Of course, other ideas except running char by char iteratively are welcome as well, run-time is important to me.

Comment: How deeply is your real data nested?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Of course, other ideas except running char by char iteratively are welcome as well, run-time is important to me.

Of course, any regex also has to run through the string character by character, too. Don't rule out the "naive" solution so easily: it turns out the simple way is more efficient than all three of the posted answers so far.

---

Here's a solution like your "naive" one: but it doesn't require a stack, because there is only one kind of open-bracket. Even with multiple kinds of brackets, you only need a stack if you also want to detect when the brackets are mismatched.

```py
def chars_at_level(s):
    out = ['<']
    nesting_level = 0

    for c in s:
        if c == '<':
            nesting_level += 1
        elif c == '>':
            nesting_level -= 1
        elif nesting_level == 1:
            out.append(c)

    out.append('>')
    return ''.join(out)
```

Example:

```py
>>> s = '<5629476219<421fsaas42f>14222<2412f2<2421savsar21>12vsaf21>412<<<142avsa1>1a24>421>421>'
>>> chars_at_level(s)
'<562947621914222412421>'
```

---

Now for the performance comparison. It beats the other three solutions, though Seb's solution is close.

```py
>>> timeit(lambda: chars_at_level(s))
7.594452977000401
>>> timeit(lambda: parse(s)) # Seb's solution using re.sub
7.817124693000096
>>> timeit(lambda: regex_sub(s)) # bobble bubble's recursive regex
9.322779934999744
>>> timeit(lambda: nested_list(s)) # Ajax1234's nested list solution
17.795835303999866
```

However, Seb's solution is much less efficient in the worst case, on strings like `<<<<<<1>>>>>>`, because it does O(*n*) replacements on strings of length O(*n*), giving a running time of O(*n*²). The other two posted solutions still seem to be about O(*n*) on this kind of string, though I had to increase the system recursion limit for Ajax1234's solution to work. The "naive" solution is still fastest.

```py
>>> t = (1000 * '<') + '1' + (1000 * '>')
>>> timeit(lambda: chars_at_level(t), number=1000)
0.1329130509998322
>>> timeit(lambda: parse(t), number=1000) # Seb's solution using re.sub
31.281542531000014
>>> timeit(lambda: regex_sub(t), number=1000) # bobble bubble's recursive regex
0.705901896999876
>>> timeit(lambda: nested_list(t), number=1000) # Ajax1234's nested list solution
1.1296931150000091
```

By the way, even if you do want to augment the "naive" solution with a stack, it still only takes O(*n*) time. It's also fairly trivial to change this algorithm to get the characters at any other nesting level, too.

Answer (score 3):

This is one way; it recursively removes inner complete tags `<[^<>]*>` until only the outer level elements remain:

```py
def parse(string):
    while True:
        output = re.sub(r'(?<!^)<([^<>]*)>(?!$)', '', string)
        if output == string:
            break
        string = output
    return output
```

```py
>>> string = '<5629476219<421fsaas42f>14222<2412f2<2421savsar21>12vsaf21>412<<<142avsa1>1a24>421>421>'
>>> parse(string)
'<562947621914222412421>'
```

```py
>>> %timeit parse(string)
6.57 µs ± 99.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

There should also be a way to do the recursion in regex itself, but I couldn't quite make it work. The built-in module `re` does not support this, but [`regex`](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) does. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26385984/recursive-pattern-in-regex) are some ideas on that.

Answer (score 3):

There is an [alternative regex module available in Python](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) that allows [recursive patterns](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-recursion.html).

With this you could use [such pattern for balanced brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/q/546433) and replace with empty string.

```
regex.sub(r'(?!^)<(?:[^><]*|(?R))+>', '', s)
```

[See this regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/cDHCtN/1) or a [Python demo](https://rextester.com/BXRDK10760), results in

> <562947621914222412421>

At `(?R)` the pattern is pasted from start, same like `(?0)`. Used [`(?!^)`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to omit [first](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `<`

Answer (score 2):

You can use recursion to create a nested list from the structure. Then, to produce the desired result, you can simply find all the top level strings in the list:

```
import re
data = '<5629476219<421fsaas42f>14222<2412f2<2421savsar21>12vsaf21>412<<<142avsa1>1a24>421>421>'
def get_data(d):
  if (val:=next(d, None)) not in {'<', '>'}:
     yield val
  if val == '<':
     yield list(get_data(d))
  if val is not None and val != '>':
     yield from get_data(d)

result = '<'+''.join(i for i in list(get_data(iter(re.findall('[^\<\>]+|[\<\>]', data))))[0] if isinstance(i, str))+'>'
```

Output:

```
'<562947621914222412421>'
```