# How to extract the operands on both sides of "==" using regex?

Tags: regex, parsing

### Language and package

python3.8, regex

### **Description**

The inputs and wanted outputs are listed as following:

> if (programWorkflowState.getTerminal(1, 2) == Boolean.TRUE) {

Want: `programWorkflowState.getTerminal(1, 2)` and `Boolean.TRUE`

> boolean ignore = !_isInStatic.isEmpty() && (_isInStatic.peek() == 3) && isAnonymous;

Want: `_isInStatic.peek()` and `3`

> boolean b = (num1 * ( 2 + num2)) == value;

Want: `(num1 * ( 2 + num2))` and `value`

### **My current regex**

`((?:\((?:[^\(\)]|(?R))*\)|[\w\.])+)\s*==\s*((?:\((?:[^\(\)]|(?R))*\)|[\w\.])+)`

This pattern want to match `\((?:[^\(\)]|(?R))*\)` or `[\w\.]` on both side of "=="

[Result on regex101.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DG9AO.png)

**Problem**: It failed to match the recursive part `(num1 * ( 2 + num2))`.

The explanation of the recursive pattern `\((?:m|(?R))*\)` is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26385984/recursive-pattern-in-regex)

But if I only use the recursive pattern, it succeeded to match `(num1 * ( 2 + num2))` as the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dMHtt.png) shows.

What's the right regex to achieve my purpose?

Comment: `\((?:m|(?R))*\)` uses `(?R)` that recurses the *entire* pattern. You need to wrap the pattern you need to recurse with a group and use a subroutine instead of `(?R)`, e.g. `(?P<aux>\((?:m|(?&aux))*\))` to recurse a pattern inside a longer one.

Comment: Thanks. The named pattern works. Finally, my regex is `((?:(?P<p1>\((?:[^\(\)]|(?&p1))*\))|(?P<p2>[\w\.]))+)\s*[!=]=\s*((?:(?&p1)|(?&p2))+)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\((?:m|(?R))*\)` pattern contains a `(?R)` construct  (equal to `(?0)` subroutine) that recurses the entire pattern.

You need to wrap the pattern you need to recurse with a group and use a subroutine instead of `(?R)` recursion construct, e.g. `(?P<aux>\((?:m|(?&aux))*\))` to recurse a pattern inside a longer one.

You can use

```
((?:(?P<aux1>\((?:[^()]++|(?&aux1))*\))|[\w.])++)\s*[!=]=\s*((?:(?&aux1)|[\w.])+)
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/a8ZpQi/1) (it takes just 6875 steps to match the string provided, [yours takes](https://regex101.com/r/a8ZpQi/2) 13680)

**Details**

- `((?:(?P<aux1>\((?:[^()]++|(?&aux1))*\))|[\w.])++)` - Group 1, matches one or more occurrences (possessively, due to `++`, not allowing backtracking into the pattern so that the regex engine could not re-try matching a string in another way if the subsequent patterns fail to match)

  - `(?P<aux1>\((?:[^()]++|(?&aux1))*\))` - an auxiliary group "aux1" that matches `(`, then zero or more occurrences of either 1+ chars other than `(` and `)` or the whole Group "aux1" pattern, and then a `)`
  - `|` - or
  - `[\w.]` - a letter, digit, underscore or `.`
- `\s*[!=]=\s*` - `!=` or `==` with zero or more whitespace on both ends
- `((?:(?&aux1)|[\w.])+)` - Group 2: one or more occurences of Group "aux" pattern or a letter, digit, underscore or `.`.