# Recursive pattern in regex for latex commands

Tags: python, regex

I need to capture the text from the `\textbf{}` command, `\textbf` will have multiple nested braces like below

`\textbf{adadasas}`

`\textbf{adadasas \textit{xxx} adasda {xxx}}`

`\textbf{adadasas {} {} {} dxxxx}`

i want to capture the value inside the \textbf{...}

i tried with the regex in python `{([^{}]*+(?:(?R)[^{}]*)*+)}` (from: [Recursive pattern in regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26385984/recursive-pattern-in-regex))

`x = regex.findall(r'\\textbf{([^{}]*+(?:(?R)[^{}]*)*+)}',cnt)`

i am not getting all the value. when removing the text `\\textbf` in the regex it is capture all the occurances.

Please suggest how to write a regex for the one

Comment: What is the expected result for each of the examples?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can repeat the first capture group `(?1)` instead of [repeating the whole pattern](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html#recursion) with `(?R)` and capture what is inside the `{}` with group 2

```
\\textbf({([^{}]*+(?:(?1)[^{}]*)*+)})
```

- `\\textbf` Match `\textbf`
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `{` Match a `{` char
  - `(` Capture **group 2**

    - `[^{}]*+` Optionally match any char except `{` `}` with a possessive quantifier

      - `(?:` Non capture group to match as a whole

        - `(?1)[^{}]*` Recurse the first [subroutine](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html#subroutines) and optionally match any char except curly's
      - `)*+` Close the non capture group and optionally repeat using a possessive quantifier
  - `)` Close group 2
  - `}` Match a `}` char
- `)` Close group 1

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/X0TRif/1)

**Note** that if you use *re.findall*, you will get all values of the capture groups returned, and this pattern has 2 capture groups.

You can use *re.finditer* instead and get the group 2 value:

```
import regex

pattern = r"\\textbf({([^{}]*+(?:(?1)[^{}]*)*+)})"

cnt = ("\\textbf{adadasas}\n"
            "\\textbf{adadasas \\textit{xxx} adasda {xxx}}\n"
            "\\textbf{adadasas {} {} {} dxxxx}\n"
            "{adadasas {} {} {} dxxxx}")

matches = regex.finditer(pattern, cnt)

for _, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):
    print(match.group(2))
```

Output

```
adadasas
adadasas \textit{xxx} adasda {xxx}
adadasas {} {} {} dxxxx
```

Comment: OP needs to understand that an extra group around the curly braces in the pattern is required, it is not the first group in the original pattern that is recursed.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes, I have added a breakdown to show where the groups are.